# APA Style: publisher as author

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

On page 203 of the APA style guide (6th ed), it reads:

> When the author and publisher are the same, use the word *Author* as
>   the name of the publisher.

An example of this is shown in the Basics Of APA Style Tutorial at apastyle.org and below.

I'm now using `biber` 0.9.6 (`biblatex` 1.7) (thanks for the tip) and I don't get this behavior by default, and I looked in **biblatex.pdf** and also **biblatex-apa.pdf** (v4.2), and I don't see this mentioned specifically in either one (although I did find section 2.3.3 Corporate Authors and Editors in **biblatex.pdf**)

Does `biblatex-apa` have this automated somehow, or do I need to write the word "Author" in the publisher field to get this type of source line in the reference list (or other work-around)?

[image: Author as Publisher]

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into this - I may have overlooked it when I wrote the style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason I didn't do this automatically is that by the time you get to the style, names have been split up into components and it's not clear what to compare any more. APA 6th just says to do this if "they are the same" which could be interpreted a number of ways. For it to be automatic, it has to be string equality, but I'm sure they also would say that "Fred Smith" and "F. Smith" were the same. What about AUTHOR="Fred Smith", PUBLISHER="Smith" - are they the same? For these reasons, I think it's probably better to just do this in the .bib. I could perhaps implement this in biber's config file mapping feature to compare fields before they are parsed and then do something. Will look into it.