# Bibliography customization - do not show publisher if it is the same as author

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am customizing the apa.bst file in order to have the style corresponding to some guidelines. The thing I am struggling with is the following rule: "Do not include the publisher when it is also the author."
As an example,

International Monetary Fund (IMF). 2015. *A report published by the IMF*. Washington, DC.

but:

Author, X. 2015. *Another book published by a publisher other than the Author*. London: Routledge.

I know that I could do it manually, as suggested for a similar question in [APA Style: publisher as author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36449/apa-style-publisher-as-author), deleting the publisher field in the .bib file, but I would rather have some programming solution to include into the .bst file, as this template will be used for different papers.
Thanks for any hints on this!

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that demonstrates your problem.